# onchange select do different mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, html

As title says I need help with onchange. I have select tag,and I need to do different mysql query when I choose something from select list. Example:

```
<select name="list">
<option>cars</option>
<option>busses</option>
<option>trucks</option>
</select>
```

and then when i select `cars` it do this

```
$query="select * from table where type='cars'";
```

and if I choose `trucks` it do

```
$query="select * from table where type='trucks'";
```

and so on...
then I need to display the result in div under the list
example

```
<select name="list">
<option>cars</option>
<option>busses</option>
<option>trucks</option>
</select>
<div> this is where I need to display results from query</div>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: do you execute query in the same page

Comment: Did we help or not? please update us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change the result by ajax :

HTML :

```
 <select id="list" name="list">

    <option>cars</option>

    <option>busses</option>

    <option>trucks</option>
    </select>
```

in JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').change(function() {
var selected=$(this).val();
  $.get("change_query.php?selected="+selected, function(data){
      $('.result').html(data);

    });
    });
});
```

and you should create change_query.php file and your query and code in it and return the result in it

```
$type = $_POST["selected"];

$query="select * from table where type='".$type."'";
```

print result here .... ;

- Tell me if you need any help ,I just guided you in Jquery not all code

Comment: I forgot to tell that I need to display that result in div on the same page. How to do that?

Comment: in JS File:

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').change(function() {
var selected=$(this).val();
  $.get("change_query.php?selected="+selected, function(data){
      $('div.result').html(data);
    });
    });
}); and in change_query.php fetch the result and print it

Comment: @EmadSamirZaki can you take a look please (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471491/onchange-function-change-the-displayed-data-from-a-table)

Answer (score 2):

You should add your SELECT code to a form with `method` attribute set to `post`,
and also a submit button of course.
Then , php will get the value of those INPUTS and do whatever you want.

```
   $term = $_POST['list'];

/*
In order to prevent unwanted queries or injection add an array with those terms and
check if the posted value is in this array:

*/
    $terms = array("cars" , "trucks");
    if(!array_key_exists($term , $terms))
     die(); //bad bad bad boy.

    $query = "select * from table where type='$term'";
```

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: and `mysql_real_escape_string` also?

Comment: No, but its worth noting that a MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: @OfirBaruch if i want to get the data from the database automatically and avoid writing them in the ` $terms = array("cars" , "trucks");` how can i do it?

Comment: This answer is really old, you should use PDO instead of mysql (as it deprecated). Using PDO you don't need to have that condition.

Answer (score -1):

you could use

```
onchange="this.form.submit();"
```

as well.